# JavaScript, Data Structure, Array Methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

Can you please explain me why if I have this array:
var array2 = ["Banana", ["Apples", ["Oranges"], "Blueberries"]];

to access "Oranges" i have to do:
array2[1][1][0];
?

Comment: `array2` is comprised of nested arrays, so subsequent indices are necessary to access the interior arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indices start from 0, so:

```
array2[1] == ["Apples", ["Oranges"], "Blueberries"]
array2[1][1] == ["Oranges"]
array2[1][1][0] == "Oranges"
```